# How to call a preexistent Python script that runs under no specific virtual environment, from a PyCharm project which does use a venv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

I have a working PyCharm project that uses a virtual environment. Now I need to call from this same project a preexistent Python script.

For reference, this second script was created with gnuradio and works in Ubuntu 20.04 shell with no specific call to any virtual environment. Actually, it should use the default /usr/bin/env.

I tried different approaches: For instance, If I call this script from shell as >> python3 preexistent_script.py, it works fine. Also, if I create a dedicated Pycharm project and properly configure the interpreter and paths, this also works. Similarly, If I create sepparate run configs for each script, both of them run properly. However, when one script calls the other, there are either coflicts with the dependencies or missing dependencies.

As a result, so far I could not find any solution to my problem. And I would be glad to hear a possible solution.